# Go func closure in loop

Tags: concurrency, go, closures

When executing the following code I get what I expect when the first loop is done (sequence from 0 to 9). But when the second loop finishes, the result is not what I expected (I expected the same result as in the first loop, but it prints only '10's):

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "sync"
)

func main() {
    var wg sync.WaitGroup

    for i := 0; i < 10; i++ {
        wg.Add(1)

        go func(j int) {
            defer wg.Done()

            fmt.Println(j)
        }(i)
    }

    wg.Wait()

    fmt.Println("done first")

    for i := 0; i < 10; i++ {
        wg.Add(1)

        go func() {
            defer wg.Done()

            fmt.Println(i)
        }()
    }

    wg.Wait()

    fmt.Println("done second")
}
```

Output:

```
0
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
done first
10
10
10
10
10
10
10
10
10
10
done second
```

Why doesn't the second loop print a sequence?

Comment: Read the documentation: [What happens with closures running as goroutines?](http://golang.org/doc/faq#closures_and_goroutines)

Comment: Thanks. Was looking in 'Effective Go' but didn't find anything. So, the FAQs hold the answer.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Because the first one gets a copy of the loop counter each time. Whereas the second gets the variable captured as part of a closure.

In the first, you're passing it in here in *every iteration of the loop*:

```
go func(j int) {
    defer wg.Done()

    fmt.Println(j)
}(i) // <------------ its passed in here as part of each loop iteration
```

The second one receives nothing.. so, the loop counter `i` is captured as part of a closure. By the time the first go routine executes, the `for` loop has finished. The loop finishing has set the `i` variable (that is now part of a closure) to 10. Go routine #1 executes and prints the value of `i`.. which is now already 10 and the rest follow suit.

TLDR: The problem here is that the loop is finishing before any go routines are scheduled to be run - its just that quick. Therefore, `i == 10` when the go routines run.

Comment: Relevant post : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/111102/how-do-javascript-closures-work